# Pyqt5 Sqlite, interface stop responding when inserting into database

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using `self.button.clicked.connect(self.createdb)` connection, where items from listwidget and combox and line are inserted into a an sqlite database.

Here is my code:

```
def createdb(self):


    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('testing.db3')
    db.open()

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("create table sas(test1 varchar(20), test2 varchar(20))")  
    for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
        query.exec_('insert into sas (test1, test2) values({}","{}")'.format(self.listWidget.item(i).text()+self.comboBox_11.currentText(), self.lineEdit.text())) 
    QtSql.QSqlDatabase.commit
    QtSql.QSqlDatabase.close

    self.statusbar.showMessage('Finished')
```

It takes ages to insert 300 values and it crushes when i want to insert 10k or more values. Any ideas why?